# array different data inside a single array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I get all this array in one array without getting it one after the other like this in the code below? i mean saving the whole data inside one variable without giving a specific index of the array

here's the code

```
const favoriteProductone = data?.getAllLikeProduct[0]
const favoriteProductTwo = data?.getAllLikeProduct[1]
const favoriteProductThree = data?.getAllLikeProduct[2]

console.log(favoriteProductone?.Like[0])
console.log(favoriteProductTwo?.Like[0])
console.log(favoriteProductThree?.Like[0])
```

Comment: You could use some extra insights on basic control flow. This is pretty basic development knowledge and you'll need it a lot. eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate the array like so:

```
if (!data) {
    throw "data is falsy - there is nothing to process";
}
data.getAllLikeProduct.forEach(p => {
    console.log(p.Like[0])
});
```